# Android 4.4 not picking background image

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a Sony Xperia Z2 Android 4.4.2 and is not showing the background image of a linearlayout, instead of that it appears a white background. This background shows perfectly in emulator and 3 different devices with android 4.2 and lower.
The image is stored in all the drawable folders (drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xhdpi..)
The XML is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.devadvance.circulartest"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView04"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
android1:background="@drawable/fondosolo"
tools:ignore="NewApi,UnusedNamespace" >
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layoutrutinaactor"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android1:background="@drawable/fondosolo" >

<ImageView
    android1:id="@+id/cabeceraactor"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:src="@drawable/cabecerastallone" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenRutinaActor"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-220.5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/imgsyl" />

<ImageView
    android1:id="@+id/imgestado"
    android1:layout_width="70dp"
    android1:layout_height="15dp"
    android1:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android1:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android1:src="@drawable/indicadorimgs2" />

<ImageView
    android1:id="@+id/textoactor"
    android1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android1:src="@drawable/textsyl" />

<Button
    android1:id="@+id/btnejercicios"
    android1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android1:background="@drawable/btnejercicios" />

<Button
    android1:id="@+id/btneliperfil"
    android1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android1:background="@drawable/btndieta" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue before and reduced the size of the image place it in resective drawable folder as mentioned here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Ofcourse it might have long height..It dosen't matter..I'm asking to reduce the size not the height

Comment: The size is 53,2KB and the measure 1080x4113px